# on click of left Navigation, Right Panel content should display

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this left navigation, for this on click of left navigation I need to display Right panel content, for this I wrote below Jquery code but no luck, can any 1 suggest me what is best way for display right content.

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Zkezz

```
("ul#main_tabs li").click(function(e){
                        if (!$(this).hasClass("selected")) {
                            var tabNum = $(this).index();
                            var nthChild = tabNum+1;
                            $("ul#main_tabs li.selected").removeClass("selected");
                            $(this).addClass("selected");
                            $("ul#Contenttab1 li.selected").removeClass("selected");
                            $("ul#Contenttab1 li:nth-child("+nthChild+")").addClass("selected");
                        }
                    });
```

image for your referece, needed this kind of output.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVAwv.png)

Comment: you can try this code for single page http://callmenick.com/post/single-page-site-with-smooth-scrolling-highlighted-link-and-fixed-navigation

Comment: your single page example is for scrolling the content on click of left navigation, I am not looking for scrolling content I need display content through hide and show just like above Jquery code... thanks for your reply..